# Trying to get the color to show

Tags: html, css

In the code, the lines are added using pseudo elements.
For some reason the colors won't show through it.

How would I get it to work using those pseudo elements in the code?

**I want to do it without adding borders, this is a must.**

**I don't want to use linear-gradient either.**

I'm really just trying to do it with just the code I have there, without anything extra added to it.

I'm already using background colors, they are just not showing through.

It's asking me to provide more info, but that's basically it.

It should look like this:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NMVw.png)

Instead it looks like this:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flzIh.png)

https://jsfiddle.net/kytc6sb0/89/

```css
    .wrap {
      position: relative;
      width: 266px;
      height: 174px;
      margin-top: 8px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .wrap a {
      float: left;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      margin: 0 4px 12px 0;
      color: transparent;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
      border: 3px solid #0059dd;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .wrap li a {
      position: relative;
      background: #ffffff;
      border: 3px solid #0059dd;
    }
    
    .wrap li a::before,
    .wrap li a::after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      width: 12px;
      height: 44px;
    }
    
    .wrap li a::before {
      left: 0;
      background: #00ffff;
    }
    
    .wrap li a::after {
      right: 0;
      background: #ff00ff;
    }
    
    li .lines a::before,
    li .lines a::after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 12px;
      width: 3px;
      height: 100%;
      background: #0059dd;
    }
    
    li .lines a::after {
      left: 29px;
    }
    
    .nav {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;
    }
    
    .hide {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="wrap">
      <ul class="nav">
    
        <li>
          <div class="lines">
            <a href="" target="_blank"></a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

Comment: Try adding `linear-gradient` `background-image` to `<a>`.

Comment: I don't want to use linear-gradient either.

Comment: Then `background-image` with `data:` uri?

Comment: I'm already using background colors in the code.

Comment: But they are cascaded? yes?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: I think the reason you are having trouble is that the selectors `li .lines a::before` and `.wrap li a::before` select the same pseudo element. It looks like your CSS is creating the color blocks, and then overwriting those to make the lines.

Comment: @peterjb How would I fix that?

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  Alberto Rivera's answer will do the trick, and I recommend accepting his answer. I was just trying to give you the why to the how. If you want to keep as much of your CSS as possible, you could change the `.wrap li a::before` (and after) selectors to just `.lines::before` (and after). Alberto Rivera's answer uses that selector as well. Check out his answer for the details of how you need to change the positioning and z-index.  The key is putting the ::before and ::after on two different elements so you get four pieces: the two lines and the two color boxes.

Comment: @peterjb Doing what you said erases the lines though? https://jsfiddle.net/kytc6sb0/181/

Comment: In lines 45, 46 and 56 of your CSS you still have the `a` as part of the selector so you are still selecting the same target twice. You will also need to adjust the height of those lines.

Comment: @peterjb The lines are still not showing after removing those a's https://jsfiddle.net/kytc6sb0/189/

Comment: Sorry, should've been more specific, there can't be a space between the `.lines` and the `::before/after`.  You wany to add the before and after pseudo elements to the `.lines` div.

Comment: But now only one of the lines is visible, the other line is missing. https://jsfiddle.net/kytc6sb0/198/

Comment: You'll need to add a `z-index` rule to the blue lines as in Alberto Rivera's answer.  That first one is being hidden by the `a` tag.

Comment: Here's is your updated jsfiddle showing both lines. If you want the lines to be more even, you may want to play with the width. https://jsfiddle.net/dgr0csyh/

Comment: Lastly, if that answered your question, please consider accepting my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Without borders**

This is more like a workaround due to your restrictions. Create another before/after element on the `lines` div, and use those ones as your lines.

https://jsfiddle.net/raj0porg/

```
.lines {
  position: relative;
}

.lines::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 44px;
  background: #00ffff;
  z-index: 1;
}

.lines::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 35px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 44px;
  background: #ff00ff;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

**Old answer**

You should use borders in addition to setting the background of the lines.

https://jsfiddle.net/qd7xLsdt/

I removed your `background`, `left` and `width` properties that affect both lines (since otherwise, the previous properties would have been overwritten):

```
li .lines a::before,
li .lines a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  //left: 12px;
  //width: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  //background: #0059dd;
}
```

I also added borders to your lines:

```
.wrap li a::before {
  left: 0;
  background: #00ffff;
  border-right: 3px solid #0059dd;
}

.wrap li a::after {
  right: 0;
  background: #ff00ff;
  border-left: 3px solid #0059dd;
}
```

Comment: I want to do it without adding borders, this is a must.

Comment: @MarvinHarris I updated the answer with a workaround that uses no gradient or borders.

Comment: I'm really just trying to do it with just the code I have there, without anything extra added to it.

Comment: If you don't want to add anything, then how do you expect things to work? What do you exactly want to change?

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning styles to elements within your CSS multiple times which ends up removing the previous style. For example you assigned the  a background of  background: #ffffff;  and later  background: #ffffff;
Another issue with you code is that you were using the pseudo elements as the border lines in the center therefore adding a background color did not show up due to the pseudo-elements not have a visible width(along with other things). 
I simply declared a width for the pseudo elements and re-positioned them within their parent. The two border lines were then obtained using border-right on a::before and border-left on a::after. The code is below.

```css
.wrap {
      position: relative;
      width: 266px;
      height: 174px;
      margin-top: 8px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .wrap a {
      position: relative;
      float: left;
      width: 50px;      /*Content: 44px  + Border: 3px + 3px */
      height: 50px;
      margin: 0 4px 12px 0;
      color: transparent;
      /* background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2); */
      border: 3px solid #0059dd;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
/* 
    .wrap li a {
      position: relative;
      background: #ffffff;
      border: 3px solid #0059dd;
    }
     */

/*  .wrap li a::before,
    .wrap li a::after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      width: 12px;
      height: 44px;
    } */
    
    .wrap li a::before {
      left: 0;
      background: #00ffff;
      border-right: 3px solid #0059dd;
    }
    
    .wrap li a::after {
      right: 0;
      background: #ff00ff;
      border-left: 3px solid #0059dd;
    }
    
    li .lines a::before,
    li .lines a::after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      /* left: 12px; */
      /* width: 3px; */
      /* (parent width / 3) - pseudoEl-border */
      width: calc( (44px / 3) - 3px);  
      height: 100%;
      /* background: #0059dd; */  
    }
    
    li .lines a::after {
      left: 29px;
    }
    
    .nav {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;
    }
    
    .hide {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <ul class="nav">

    <li>
      <div class="lines">
        <a href="http://hi5.1980s.fm/played.html" target="_blank" title="Song History"></a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```